# How would one make a custom inspector for built-in assets?

Tags: unity, c#, editors, asset-workflow

I'm trying to see how I could either modify, append or completely override what the inspector shows for a selected built-in asset.

Specifically, I want to override what the inspector shows when you select image files in the project tab. I was hoping to make it so I could have a button that I could click that could, say, modify the file name of the asset.

What needs to be overridden or inherited to make this happen? Is this even allowed?

Comment: You can rename *any* asset by simply selecting it and pressing F2. This change will be reflected project-wide.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking how to modify what the inspector shows, the filename was simply an example of what I would want to modify the inspector to do.

Comment: What kind of things you want to do that the Unity inspector doesn't provide? There may be easier ways than creating a whole custom inspector

Comment: @NoshWare What I mean is, many actions you can do without Inspector-exposed buttons because they belong to a different context. Renaming, moving and deleting assets is achieved via the filesystem. Custom windows, inspectors and property drawers are intended for scripts because they're the core of game programming. OTOH, there's no real advantage in supporting a custom editor for visualising images, I guess.

Comment: I was hoping to have a pane that allows the modification of an image's pixel data (ex. red channel +100 to change its colour for example). This would then modify the file itself. The reason I was avoiding saying this is that I understand how to modify an image file via C#, I was needing help on how I display this in the inspector for this built-in asset type. Would this clear things up?